# Gnome-panel applet "Indicator Applet Complete" is missing icons

Tags: gnome-panel

I have a Gnome session definition with XMonad as windows manager where I start the **gnome-panel explicitly**. The session definition looks like this:

```
[GNOME Session]
Name=GNOME + XMonad
RequiredComponents=xmonad;gnome-flashback-init;gnome-flashback;gnome-panel;nautilus-classic;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Clipboard;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings;
```

With this setup in one english language Ubuntu 18.10 installation the gnome-panel pops up like this:

[image]

I tried all applets available but none is supplying the set of items combined in one applet that I see on another german Ubuntu 18.10 installation starting the Gnome shell (gnome-panel), **this is the appet layout that I really want**:

[image]

The above applet contains all the relevant pieces in on applet.

I think both are called "**Indicator Applet Complete**" but does anybody know why one version is only showing 2 icons while the other shows all icons?

Comment: What you call `gnome-panel` isn't the GNOME panel of old. It's just GNOME shell with some extensions.

Comment: On MATE Panel it is named `indicator-applet-complete` if it helps... @muru `gnome-panel` is still available on 18.10, we can get GNOME FlashBack session based on it.

Comment: @muru: I start the panel with command ```gnome-panel```

Comment: @N0rbert : I have installed package ```indicator-applet-complete``` and added the "Indicator Applet Complete" but somehow the icons are still only 2 (up-down arrow and mail) The rest of the icons that  I'm used to are mssing. Any idea?

Comment: @N0rbert and Konrad call it whatever, it's *not* the gnome-panel of GNOME 2. It's just GNOME shell dressed up differently. You're better off looking for additional extensions for GNOME shell.

Comment: @muru. Ok then you are right. I'll call it shell, any more input?

Comment: @muru You are wrong, GNOME Flashback does use `gnome-panel` and it has nothing to do with GNOME Shell and/or with its extensions. There is GNOME Classic session that is `gnome-shell` + extensions.

Comment: @KonradEisele How are you starting your session? And what do you mean with "I start the gnome-panel explicitly"?

Comment: @muktupavels : I use there session definitions: https://github.com/eiselekd/dotfiles/tree/master/gnome. Then I select it in the  GDM login. The default panel is xmobar, however when I press win-shift-g I start the ```gnome-panel``` ontop of xmobar, see startgpanel https://github.com/eiselekd/dotfiles/blob/master/.xmonad/xmonad.hs function ```startgpanel```

Comment: @KonradEisele `DesktopNames` in `gnome-xmonad.desktop` should be `DesktopNames=GNOME-Flashback;GNOME;` not `DesktopNames=Unity`. You might try to change `Exec` line like here - https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-gnome-flashback/gnome-flashback/tree/debian/patches/run-systemd-session.diff

Comment: @muktupavels : Thanks for the tip. I dont have any problem with the config file. The problem was that the gnome-panel applet "Indicator Applet Complete" needed its child apps to be started explicitly. See the answer from N0rbert below and "systemctl --user start". Without these lines the gnome-panel icons where missing.

Comment: @KonradEisele That is because default GNOME Flashback sessions are started by systemd. See also this file - https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-gnome-flashback/gnome-flashback/tree/debian/gnome-session-flashback.target#n9. So you can try to change `gnome-xmonad.desktop` to use `run-systemd-session`...

Comment: @muktupavels : Now I understand what you mean. Thanks, that is also a possibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all GNOME Panel is still GNOME Panel, not GNOME Shell.
I have no `gnome-shell` executables in process list  while selected GNOME FlashBack session from GDM. The **GNOME Flashback (Metacity)** has all indicators in place automatically.

As far I can see on clean minimal 18.10 install - the `xmonad` package provides session file:

```
$ dpkg -S ".session" | grep "session$"
gdm3: /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-login.session
ubuntu-session: /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu.session
xmonad: /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-flashback-xmonad.session # <---
```

and the `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-flashback-xmonad.session` contains the following (differ from your only by `nautilus-classic`):

```
$ cat /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-flashback-xmonad.session
[GNOME Session]
Name=GNOME Flashback (Xmonad)
RequiredComponents=gnome-flashback-init;gnome-flashback;gnome-panel;xmonad;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Clipboard;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings;
```

In GDM3 this session is labeled as **GNOME Flashback (Xmonad)**.

So I installed the components mentioned above with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

Even after installation of full `unity-desktop` package I can't get all indicators in place automatically.

But I can get them manually:

```
systemctl --user start indicator-power.service
systemctl --user start indicator-keyboard.service
systemctl --user start indicator-sound.service
systemctl --user start indicator-datetime.service
systemctl --user start indicator-session.service

# and optionally
systemctl --user start indicator-application.service
systemctl --user start indicator-bluetooth.service
systemctl --user start indicator-messages.service
systemctl --user start indicator-printers.service
```

So I have:

[image: manual load]

Comment: Answer updated - we can get indicators loaded manually.

Comment: With the systemctl commands I have the icons I'm used to back! I was trying to get this work the whole afternoon. This rabbithole I can now jump over. Thanks.

Comment: I had the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with gnome-flashback and xmonad after updating yesterday. Loading the indicators manually with the provided commands temporarily fix this issue too.